# Which ip ranges does the google container registry use for its build tools?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry, google-container-builder

I'm working with some custom libraries, which are hosted on a private pypi server (running in a Google Compute Engine instance).

I would like to include the libraries when deploying an app to Google App Engine, and am wondering if it's possible to open up the private pypi firewall only to the Google Cloud Platform build servers.

Is there an easy way for me to set up firewall rules to grant the Google Container Registry build servers access into my GCE backed pypi server?

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend attempting this sort of security via firewall rules as we cannot give you a list of IP addresses that we can be sure (1) won't change and (2) will only be used by [Google Container Builder](http://cloud.google.com/container-builder/). Instead, I would recommend that you use Cloud KMS to include encrypted credentials in your build and authenticate the requests to your private servers. We have [docs on using encrypted files here](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/tutorials/using-encrypted-files) (and some additional documentation on encrypted secrets is coming soon).

Comment: You mean we should open up access to our private servers generally over the internet/https, and authenticate requests?

Comment: I'm saying that the IP addresses we use are ephemeral. Only proper authentication and authorization will give you security. For additional details, see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#where_can_i_find_short_product_name_ip_ranges

Comment: Assuming that we already have proper authentication and authorization in place, is there any additional security benefit to restricting access at the firewall (or is that step a waste)?

Comment: Given that any of the IP addresses used by Google Container Builder could be reassigned to any GCP user at some other time, I don't think this provides you with much additional security at all. Perhaps it nominally protects you from a DOS attack in that you drop traffic from the rest of the internet.

Comment: @DavidBendory - I'm looking to give Cloud Builder access to my database during the steps. But I'd been restricting access to the db to just machines in my network. Any suggestions on how to handle this authorization without exposing the db to the world?  

(Context: I'm working around a rails bug where asset compilation requires database access during the compilation phase)

Comment: @JeffD Please contact us at gcr-contact@google.com to discuss your use case more thoroughly (and privately).

Comment: @DavidBendory - Thank you for the offer. I found a workaround where I just created an empty database that was publicly accessible. Going forward, Rails 5 is abandoning its asset pipeline in favor of Webpack, which should completely eliminate the problem. So I won't burden your team with work for such an edge case. :-) Thank you for the reply though!

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/set-up-gke) will help you to create a firewall rule to allow certain IPs and GCR calls will use those IP's only