# Trigger Jenkins from GCR image push (with pub/sub)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, google-container-registry

There is official support for dockerhub: https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/plugins/dockerhub-trigger

However, there is not for GCR (please correct me if I'm wrong).

GCR doesn't support webhooks and even if it did I wouldn't want to setup network access to my Jenkins server because I wouldn't have IPs to whitelist: [Which ip ranges does the google container registry use for its build tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597874/which-ip-ranges-does-the-google-container-registry-use-for-its-build-tools)

Is there a way to have Jenkins poll Google pub/sub? I couldn't find a plugin for that.

I could do something like GCR => trigger pub/sub => trigger VPC-ed cloud function => call Jenkins job but that's a big mess, adds more stuff that could break and have to maintain.

What I would prefer is to just set a trigger like I can poll my SCM repos (I use webhooks for SCM but polling is possible and officially supported).

Is there a plugin that could do something as seamless as adding a pub/sub "trigger"? https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers

Also, maybe I could do something like run a job on a schedule that checks GCR every minute or whatever but that seriously clutters up my build history and seems like a wonky way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin that does all that, definitely not; I think that using Pub/Sub the more close that you could get, is to use something like the [URLTrigger plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/urltrigger/) to call the pubsub API directly; however, this doesn't solve the issue on the authentication, and how to implement the logic to trigger or not a build.

Considering my last statement, your solution could be given in parts, such as,

1. configure that the 'repositories' send the notification to pub / sub
2. configure a plugin in jenkins that reads pub / sub to monitor push (e.g. https://github.com/jenkinsci/pubsub-light-plugin)
3. configure it to send call / notify jenkins
4. run the task in jenkins if step 2 was successful

I hope it helps you to find a clear path to your issue.